# meaning of {0[7-9],1*,2*}

Tags: shell-script, shell

What the command below will do and what output will it give?

```
echo "{$begin_dt/{0[7-9],1*,2*},$dates/*,$next_dt/0[0-6]}"
```

Where `$begin_dt` and `$next_dt` are dates.

Comment: Which shell are you using? Can you show us an example of $begin_dt and $next_dt?

Comment: Have you tried the command? Are you *sure* that's the command you are looking for? It doesn't do anything fancy. The simple answer is: just run it and see. It is not a dangerous command, all it does is `echo` (print) some variables.

Answer (score 2):

There's a slight difference between the string in the question title, and the string in the question itself. Namely, the latter is in quotes, the one in the title isn't.

*Outside* quotes, the [braces `{...}` expand](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) to the string next to the braces concatenated to all the comma-separated strings within the braces. i.e. `string{this,that}` expands to `stringthis` and `stringthat`, saving you from repeating the common part.

Filename globbing would happen after that, so something like `dir/{0[7-9],1*,2*}` would expand to `dir/0[7-9]`, `dir/1*` and `dir/2*` all of which would then be expanded to matching filenames.

If the filenames are days of the month in two-digit numbers, it would match numbers 07 to 29. (but not 30 or 31!)

The outer set of braces in the example would be expanded similarly.

*Inside* quotes, the braces are nothing special, and neither is filename expansion done, so all that gets expanded is the variables.

This in Bash and other shells that have brace expansion, it's not a feature of POSIX sh.